# How do I get in js time difference between two timezones?

Tags: javascript

I have clients' timezone in database, for example it is `Asia/Nicosia`.

I want to show to another site user HIS offset from that user. Lets say he lives in Moscow and is having

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

How do I get in js time difference between `Europe/Moscow` and `Asia/Nicosia`?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: If all you want is the difference, create a Date object for a set date/time (like now, or a specific DT), parse that date to each of the two time zones, and compare the difference.

Comment: I tried, but looks like its impossible to create date setting specific timezone. At least I couldnt.

Comment: @Amy I know that lib, but its to heavy to download whole lib for simple comparison of two timezone, which natively supported nowdays in `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` object. There HAS to be native way.